# Is there a way to see column 'grams' of the TfidfVectoririzer output?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I want to visualize "Words/grams" used in columns of TfidfVectorizer outut in python-scikit library . Is there a way ?

I tried to to convert csr to array , but cannot see header composed of grams.

Comment: Do you mean n-grams? Try the `get_feature_names` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use get_feature_names method as specified in comments by larsmans